# Test for Heteroscedasticity on a caret nnet model

Tags: r, r-caret

Is there a function within `caret` (or another package) that can perform a Breusch-Pagan / Cook-Weisberg test for heteroskedasticity on an 'nnet' model trained using `caret`?

E.g. something similar to `library(car); ncvTest` or `library(lmtest); bptest` for `lm` objects, but that works on `nnet` objects created from `caret`?

**Example data**

```
library(caret)
set.seed(4)
n <- 100    
x1i <- rnorm(n)
x2i <- rnorm(n)
yi  <- rnorm(n)

dat <- data.frame(yi, x1i, x2i)

mod <- train(yi ~., data=dat, method="nnet", trace=FALSE, linout=TRUE)
```

This produces the plot of fitted vs residuals:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not anything like that in the package right now.

Comment: short but sweet. You say 'right now', does that imply it's on the 'to implement' list?